# Does anyone say "I have a bad feeling about this" in episode VIII

Tags: dialogue, star-wars, the-last-jedi

Is the quote present in all other Star Wars movies, heard in *Star Wars: The Last Jedi*?

Comment: I think one of the Porgs says it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Director **Rian Johnson** [tweeted](https://twitter.com/rianjohnson/status/941235366853529600):

> **It’s in there!**

and in an [interview with the Huffpost](https://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/rian-johnson-last-jedi-star-wars-easter-egg_us_5a343517e4b01d429cc8bd59?ncid=inblnkushpmg00000009) he confirmed that

> **the line came from BB-8′s anxious beeps when the droid and Poe Dameron
>   (Oscar Isaac) are flying into battle against the First Order near the
>   start of the movie**
>   
> [image: BB-8]
>   
> ***“It seemed like a fun character to deliver that line. I think originally I had Poe respond, ‘Oh, I got a good feeling about it. Keep your chin up.’ And then I made it a little less explicit just to make it more fun.”***

Comment: How someone is supposed to understand that beeps of a droid unless it is subtitled? I answered as per the dialogues. *Sighs*

Comment: @AJ  By what the human side of the conversation; it's a fun and fine way to include the easter egg. So are you complaining that you couldn't hear the line explicitly or just that you didn't get the accepted answer?

Comment: @AgustínLado   I have no objection for which answer is accepted (I don't know where this idea came from. I upvoted this answer). I am just saying that I didn't hear the line explicitly.

Comment: I agree with @AJ.  This is some weak shit.  It may be what BB-8 said according to the director.  However, no one in our world speaks droid.

Answer (score 12):

It seems The Last Jedi is the first movie to skip this quote.

According to [this review](https://www.heypoorplayer.com/2017/12/14/star-wars-the-last-jedi-review/),

> Oh, and maybe I missed it, but **this might be the very first theatrically released Star Wars film not to include the famous line**, “I have a bad feeling about this.” I did not pick up on it during either viewing.

Also from this [Wikia article](http://fandom.wikia.com/articles/the-last-jedi-all-the-cameos-and-easter-eggs-we-spotted),

> **The line “I have a bad feeling about this” is conspicuous in its absence**, but there’s one callback to a classic Star Wars line that’s easy to miss.

Answer (score -3):

I did not hear it; nor did my wife. There are other echoes of original trilogy lines, including a subtle one.